# Integral wrt floor(x)

Tags: definite-integrals

What is the definite integral of $f(x)=x^2+1$ with respect to the differential of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ i.e ($d\lfloor x\rfloor$) from $0$ to $2$?

I tried to multiply and divide dx by then $d\lfloor x\rfloor/dx = 0$.

How do I approach it?

Comment: do you mean $\int_0^2 (x^2+1)d\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: @Wouter Well yes, we in India use that notation.

Comment: $d\lfloor x\rfloor$ is not everywhere zero, in particular it is not zero at $x=1$. Are you familiar with the [dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)?

Comment: @Wouter The dirac delta function?

Comment: @Wouter Not that much but yes, please explain.

Comment: I think your question is about Riemann–Stieltjes integral ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Integrate by parts ( Why not ? ):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,5px]{%
\int_{0}^{2}\pars{x^{2} + 1}\dd\lfloor x\rfloor}
\\[3mm] = &\
\overbrace{\left.\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\pars{x^{2} + 1}
\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 2}}^{\ds{=\ 10}}\ -\
\int_{0}^{2}\lfloor x\rfloor\pars{2x}\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
10\ -\ \underbrace{2\int_{0}^{1}\lfloor x\rfloor\,\dd x}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\ -\ \underbrace{2\int_{1}^{2}\lfloor x\rfloor x\,\dd x}_{\ds{=\ 3}} =
\bbox[10px,#ffa,border:1px groove navy]{7} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

AS a hint:an example

$$\int_{2}^{7} t^2 \, d\lfloor t \rfloor = 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 = 135$$
For the former, $t↦⌊t⌋$ increases only at its jumps on [$2,7]$, which are precisely $t=3,4,5,6,7$. Since the jump sizes are identically 1,

Comment: How did you arrived at this?

Comment: To explain why, look back at the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^bf(t)dg(t)$. Around a jump, there will be some interval $(xi,x_{i+1})$ and the contribution to the integral will be $f(x∗i)(g(x_{i+1})−g(xi))$, where $x∗i \in (xi,x_{i+1})$. As the length of the interval shrinks to zero, the expression limits to the size of the jump times the value of f at the location of the jump.

Comment: Got it now thanks!

Comment: may help you:https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesIntegral.html